# Can't click the upvote on my angular-rails Reddit clone

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I built a Reddit clone in Angular and Rails following this [guide](https://thinkster.io/angular-rails). I've been playing around with the CSS to get the upvote and downvote arrows in the right spot. I guess overriding the Bootstrap wasn't a good idea because I can't seem to get my ng-click to fire when I click the arrow anymore (it worked fine before, didn't change the js at all). Here's the relevant bits:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1 small-right-gutters small-col">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1 small-right-gutters">
                <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" ng-click="addUpvote(post)"></div>
                <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 vert-center">
                {{post.upvotes}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 big-col vert-center">
        <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
            {{post.title}}
        </a>
        <span ng-hide="post.link">
            {{post.title}}
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 text-right">
        <div>
            <small><a href="#/posts/{{post.id}}">{{ post.comments.length }} comment<span ng-hide="post.comments.length==1">s</span></a></small>
        </div>
        <div>
            <small>posted by <a ng-href="#/users/{{post.user.username}}">{{post.user.username}}</a></small>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.small-right-gutters {
    padding-right: 2px;
}

.small-col {
    width: 40px;
}

.big-col {
    width: 925px;
    font-size:20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.vert-center {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

Angular controller:

```
$scope.addUpvote = function (post) {
    postFactory.upvotePost(post);
};
$scope.addDownvote = function (post) {
    postFactory.downvotePost(post);
};
```

Angular factory:

```
upvotePost: function(post) {
    return $http.put('/posts/' + post.id + '/upvote.json').success(function (data) {
        post.upvotes += 1;
    });
},
downvotePost: function(post) {
    return $http.put('/posts/' + post.id + '/downvote.json').success(function (data) {
        post.upvotes -= 1;
    });
},
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add `z-index: 1;` on your `.glyphicon` it works!